# Enabling test coverage and reporter-html in jest Disable errors in CLI

Tags: testing, jestjs

Today I enabled the jest settings to generate code coverage and also generate the html-reporter, however, when I do that, jest no longer shows individual test errors on the command line, so I don't know which expected is wrong and which line displays this error, what should I enable to get it back to normal without losing jest coverage?

[image]

Comment: You can add multiple reporters: https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#reporters-arraymodulename--modulename-options

Comment: thank you, you are my savior!! How to put your answer as the solution?